# Summation of specific items in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a data file such as:

```
1  123  something else
2  234  something else
3  500  something else
.
. 
.
1  891  something else
2  234  something else
3  567  something else 
.
.
.
```

I am trying to end up with a file with:

```
1 1014
2  468
3 1067
```

That is, add the numbers in column 2 (or some other column) if the number in column 1 is the same. I believe reading the columns into a nested list and proceeding from there is the way to go but I have been struggling with that. Another approach I tried was creating a new file with the entries I am interested in:

```
for next in f.readlines():
    output.write(next[0:1] + "," + next[3:6]+ "\n")
    if not next:
        break

with open(output,"r") as file:
    data_list=[[int(x) for x in line.split(",")] for line in file]

print data_list
```

This returns

```
[[1, 123], [2, 234], [3, 500], [1, 891], [2, 234], [3, 567]]
```

I guess I could loop through that list and compare data_list[x][0] and add the values if they match but that does not seem like an elegant solution.
Could anyone suggest a more elegant way of doing this?
Especially, I have been struggling with summation of specific items in the nested list I end up with.

Comment: Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) of lists: `{1: [123, 891, ...], ...}`.

Comment: Your code example doesn't make sense. What's output? why not work direct w/ file object f? and... I wouldn't be so explicit taking next[3:6], but maybe splitting the line with .split('\t') and taking the [1] element

Comment: Thank you for the comments and sorry about the confusion. I was leaving out a bit of code to make it more readable, guess it had the opposite effect. Anyways, the reason for explicitly taking next[3:6] is due to the way the data file is set up, which is out of my control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary to track the sum; using a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes it a little easier to start keys at 0 if they haven't been seen before:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sums = defaultdict(int)

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        col1, col2, rest = line.split(None, 2)
        sums[col1] += int(col2)
```

This reads your initial file, splits the line on whitespace 2 times to get the first two columns out, then sums the second column based on the first:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> sample = '''\
... 1  123  something else
... 2  234  something else
... 3  500  something else
... 1  891  something else
... 2  234  something else
... 3  567  something else 
... '''.splitlines()
>>> sums = defaultdict(int)
>>> for line in sample:
...     col1, col2, rest = line.split(None, 2)
...     sums[col1] += int(col2)
... 
>>> sums
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1': 1014, '3': 1067, '2': 468})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I did not include this in my initial post but actually the data files I work with sometimes contain large numbers so that no white spaces exist between the columns. Rather,the columns are predefined as e.g column1: 1-4, column2: 5-7. Is there a way to define col1 as character[0:4], col2 as character[5:7] etc? Hope that made sense. If this cannot be easily incorporated I will just make a new file, as by my original post, and then use the code you have provided.

Comment: @user2913053: just slice your numbers like that then; instead of the `line.split()` just use `col1 = line[:4].strip()` (removing extra whitespace after slicing) and `col2 = int(line[5:7])` and `sums[col1] += col2`.

Comment: I think you should convert the key to an int too, otherwise i also really likes this solution ;)

Comment: I assumed the first column is an opaque value; it could be an int, or something else. It doesn't matter for grouping here if we leave it a string or convert it to an int.