# fast sorting of a csv file?

Tags: python, sorting, python-itertools

I am somewhat new to python - and trying to learn python for data analysis primarily. I have a CSV file which looks like so (ID,category):

```
67512367,0
67567,5
89789789,5
...
...
876289347,10
638, 10
...
...
98723489,20
3828909, 20
...
...<going upto>
78789789, 200
978789, 200
```

What I'd like to do is to sort the IDs according to their categories. So, at the end I would like something which looks like this:

```
list_5 = [67567, 89789789, .., ]
list_10 = [876289347, 638, ...]
list_200 = [78789789, 978789, ...]
```

The problem is that the CSV file has around 1.5 million entries. So, I load them at the moment using izip and csv reader like so:

```
data = izip(csv.reader(open("data.csv", "rb")))
```

and I have the entries in `data` which I am able to iterate using simply:

```
for i in data:
    print i
    #print i[0][0] # for ids
    #print i[0][1] # for category
```

Now, I know that I can use an if-else/elif construct to check if `i[0][1]==5` and then append `i[0][0]`(the ID) to a list, but this would seem very slow - and my list is large.

I was wondering if there was any other elegant way (maybe something using itertools?) to `bucketize` the IDs based on the value of the second column (the category).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25184415/3001761 - the same solution (`defaultdict(list)`) will work here, too - `{5: [67567, 89789789, ...], ...}`.

Comment: This is pretty amazing - never knew of collections before. Solved the problem in under a minute. Thanks a tonne for this. If you could put this down as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Just pointing out that your call to `izip` doesn't actually do anything for you here. Just remove it and it'll work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you're "trying to learn python for data analysis primarily", you should definitely look at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) so you can have a better toolset to play with.  (That's not to say that it's not useful to know how to built pandas-like tools from scratch, of course.  But in my experience even with pandas you have more than enough chances to exercise your Python skills, and it's more interesting to figure out how to do something real than it is to figure out how to reimplement basic functionality.)

You could read your file into a DataFrame (like an Excel sheet) using `read_csv`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("group.csv", names=["ID", "category"])
>>> df
          ID  category
0   67512367         0
1      67567         5
2   89789789         5
3  876289347        10
4        638        10
5   98723489        20
6    3828909        20
7   78789789       200
8     978789       200
```

And then build a dictionary of the categories-to-ids using `groupby`:

```
>>> {k: v.tolist() for k,v in df.groupby("category")["ID"]}
{0: [67512367], 200: [78789789, 978789], 10: [876289347, 638], 20: [98723489, 3828909], 5: [67567, 89789789]}
```

Although you can also do a lot of operations on `groupby` objects directly (like computing statistics, etc) so to be honest I don't often need an actual list of the indices.  More frequently I just want "do this operation on every group", but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks DSM for this - I will look at pandas. Have you looked at johnsharpes comment? That to me seems to be the quickest way to do sort. Thoughts?

Comment: @JohnJ: it's a little confusing to call it a sort.  I wouldn't worry much about performance, though: 1.5M lines is pretty few, so anything you do to it which is linear should be speedy.  You might even be dominated by I/O time, although that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
# test_big.csv was 1.74GB
def test():
    from itertools import groupby
    bucketized_grouped_keys = {}
    with open('test_big','r') as f:
        for key, group in groupby(f,lambda T: T.split(',')[1].rstrip('\n')):
                bucketized_grouped_keys.update({key:group})
    print(bucketized_grouped_keys.keys())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cProfile
    cProfile.run('test()','test.profile')
    import pstats
    stats = pstats.Stats('test.profile')
    stats.strip_dirs().sort_stats('time').print_stats()
```

Output:

```
['47', '44', '2', '42', '49']
Thu Aug 07 10:55:39 2014    test.profile

         445620949 function calls in 239.002 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
148540313   95.738    0.000  178.467    0.000 csv_test.py:6(<lambda>)
        1   60.535   60.535  239.002  239.002 csv_test.py:2(test)
148540313   55.128    0.000   55.128    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
148540313   27.601    0.000   27.601    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}

        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
        1    0.000    0.000  239.002  239.002 <string>:1(<module>)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects
}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Prof
iler' objects}
```

The key function is:

```
lambda T: T.split(',')[1].rstrip('\n')
```

which is the same as:

```
def T(item):
    return item.split(',')[1].rstrip('\n')
```

To access the groups:

```
category_name = '42'
bucketized_grouped_keys[category_name]
```

Comment: Although your solution is working as expected, I like what johnrsharpe has suggested. Basically, it is only two lines: `d = defaultdict(list)` and then `for i in data: d[i[0][1]].append(i[0][0])` and thats it. d['5'] then gives me all the `bucketized` values as a neat list. Basic info seems to be here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 0):

Call sort twice.

```
sortedCats = sorted(data, key=attrgetter('category_name'))
sortedIds = sorted(sortedCats, key=attrgetter('id'))
```

This works because the sort algorithm used in python is [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), and the second sort uses the groups created by the first sort to do less work.